# reading mp3 tags on the www with python

Tags: python, tags, mp3

I've found a few modules to read mp3 tags with python -- for example mutagen and id3. When doing this online, I was wondering if the modules were accessing the whole file or just the last 128 bites that contained the tag info. 
Thanks

Edit: 
When I say accessing, I mean caching to access the file data. At least that's what I think it means XD

Answer (score 0):

mutagen reads [last 128 bytes for id3](https://github.com/nex3/mutagen/blob/master/mutagen/id3.py#L125)

id3 similarly:

```
self.title = self.file.read(30)
self.artist = self.file.read(30)
self.album = self.file.read(30)
self.year = self.file.read(4)
self.comment = self.file.read(30)
```

Comment: The Mutagen comment is a little off; ID3v1 tags are at the end of the file. The piece of code you quoted just reads MPEG stream info, not necessarily the ID3v2 tag (which is at the start of the file). After all, the tags may be much longer than 32k, what with embedded images and so on.

Comment: Still a little bit off, I'm afraid. See line 122 in the above-linked id3.py; it seeks until 128 bytes from the end of the file before reading 128 bytes. The OP seems to be asking about reading tag data over HTTP; using the HTTP HEAD verb, reading the resultant Content-Length, then requesting partial content with the Bytes: header might just do the trick.